# returning array using functions - c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to pass an array in a function and then printing it out the values found inside the array.

this is what I have

numbers.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "numbers.h"

int * numbers::printNumbers()    {

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
            arrayOne[j] =i;
        }
    }
    return arrayOne;
}
```

numbers.h

```
#ifndef try_numbers_h
#define try_numbers_h
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class numbers   {

public:

      int * printNumbers();

private:

      int arrayOne[4];
};

#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "numbers.h"

int main () {
    numbers printNum;
    int * p;
    p = printNum.printNumbers();

}
```

the codes shown above, run successfully

but my output is returning some weird memory address

output

```
0x7fff5fbff8e0
```

by right it should output

expect output

```
0
1
2
3
```

Comment: Standard answer 1A: use `std::vector` instead of an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your code is correct.**

The memory address it is printing is the address of the beginning of the class variable `arrayOne`. The reason you are seeing that instead of:

```
0
1
2
3
```

Is that this bit of code:

```
numbers printNum;
int * p;
p = printNum.printNumbers();
```

is only being assigned the **address** of the array `arrayOne`, not the *value* of its contents.

Which brings us to another issue: you are not seeing any output as you are **not** printing out the data at each array index (as shown in your code).

To do so, you should iterate over the pointer *to the array* `arrayOne` and output them so you can see/verify your expected results.

However, as your current methodology violates the principle of least surprise (as the name of your method is `printNumbers` (but doesn't print numbers and returns the address of the array), then it it is a good idea to refactor your code so that your function `printNumbers` prints the numbers (and doesn't return the address of the array).

And, given that arrays do have a built in sense of dimension in them (i.e. they are not aware of their own dimensionality, it would be better as others have suggested to use a `std::vector` instead as this is safer, cleans up after itself, and has a lot more functionality/benefits over C-Style arrays with similar performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `arrayOne` public and `printNumbers()` void. Then in main.cpp do the following: 1) execute function `printNum.printNumbers()` 2) assign to the `p` your `printNum.arrayOne`.
Hope this helps!